# How to order an array of randomly drawn ellipses by size before drawing them

Tags: matlab

matlab beginner here and a big thanks in advance.i'm having trouble with an existing program:

The purpose of this project is to build (6) layers of randomly sized and oriented ellipses on a background, then save each layer state as a separate image (i.e. image1 with just background, image2 with bg and 1 ellipse, image3 with bg and 2 ellipses, etc...). As of now, the program works but sometimes some of the ellipses become hidden in the final picture (with 6 ellipses) if one of the later objects is bigger than an earlier one. I was that one possible solution to this would be to save the ellipse values in an array but not export them yet as an image. Once they are all saved, calculate area of each then use a sort function to put them in descening order and then draw and export them.

Here is the code as it stands:

```
xdim=1280; ydim=1024;       % screen dimensions - these should match the touch screen dimensions

scene=zeros(xdim,ydim,3);

for scene_counter=1:1 %amount of scenes generated

    scene_counter
    figure;

    ell_size_min=100; ell_size_max=800; % range of axis lengths for ellipses/pacman

    min_color_separation=0.15;  % this could theoretically take values between 0 and sqrt(3)=1.73ish
    % if you increase this, it will take the program longer to find an acceptable set of colors
    % the probability that a set of colors fails the separation test & it has to get a new one is
    % about 10% for 0.1; about 50% for 0.15 and about 70% for 0.2

    %-------------------------------------------
    scene=scene.*0;

    p = randperm(4);    % creates random permutation of (1-4)
    bg_count=p(1)+2;    % selects first integer in sequence, e.g. random 1-4
    % number of bg elements, min 3, max 6.

    %-------------------------------------------
    % this bit spaces out the colors of background and foreground elements
    % it checks that ALL combinations have a min separation in color space using Pythagoras' theorum
    % here color space is defined as 0 < R,G,B < 1
    % it picks 11 spaced colors for each scene -
    %   7 possible ellipses/pacmen + 3 letters (s+,s-,big letter) + background 'field' ie the very background

    color_check_flag=1;
    while color_check_flag==1
        colors=rand(11, 3);

        color_check=...
            [colors-repmat(colors(1,:),11,1);...
            colors-repmat(colors(2,:),11,1);...
            colors-repmat(colors(3,:),11,1);...
            colors-repmat(colors(4,:),11,1);...
            colors-repmat(colors(5,:),11,1);...
            colors-repmat(colors(6,:),11,1);...
            colors-repmat(colors(7,:),11,1);...
            colors-repmat(colors(8,:),11,1);...
            colors-repmat(colors(9,:),11,1);...
            colors-repmat(colors(10,:),11,1);...
            colors-repmat(colors(11,:),11,1) ];

        color_check_flag=sum(sqrt(sum((color_check+(color_check==0)).^2,2))<min_color_separation)>0;
    end;

    %-------------------------------------------
    % this bit makes the background of the scene
    % first, it makes a matrix the size of the screen and lets the elements be 1 if they fall in the ellipse or zero otherwise
    % then, it takes out a bite if the bg element should be a pacman (random, p=0.5)
    % then, it converts the matrix defining the shape into a 3d matrix, the size of the screen x 3 for RGB intensities
    %   that matrix defines this bg element, or 'layer' fully
    % it combines layers in another screen size x 3 matrix -
    %   to do this is blanks (makes then =0) any elements in the scene which should be overwriten by the new bg element
    %   and then adds the new bg element to the scene

    im = zeros(xdim,ydim);
    [x,y] = ind2sub(size(im),1:numel(im));

    bg=reshape([ones(xdim,ydim).*rand,ones(xdim,ydim).*rand,ones(xdim,ydim).*rand,],xdim,ydim,3);
    imwrite(permute(bg,[2 1 3]),['scene_' int2str(scene_counter) '_' int2str(1) '.jpg'], 'jpg');

    for i=1:6


        a=rand*(ell_size_max-ell_size_min)+ell_size_min;    % a is one axis of ellipse
        b=rand*(ell_size_max-ell_size_min)+ell_size_min;    % b is the other axis
        centre = [rand*xdim rand*ydim];             % background elements can be anywhere on screen

        ellipse = (x-centre(1)).^2 / a^2 + (y-centre(2)).^2/b^2 < 1;    % define which pixels fall in the ellipse

        % this bit makes the ellipse into pacman

        if rand<0.5

            bite_start=(rand*2*pi)-pi;
            bite_stop=(rand*2*pi)-pi;

            [theta,rho] = cart2pol(y-centre(2),x-centre(1));    % generate polar coords for doing the pacman mouth
            if bite_stop>bite_start
                pacman=(bite_start<theta).*(theta<bite_stop);
            else
                pacman=(theta>bite_start)+(bite_stop>theta);
            end

            ellipse=(reshape(ellipse.*pacman,xdim,ydim));
        end


        layer=reshape([ellipse.*colors(i,1) ellipse.*colors(i,2) ellipse.*colors(i,3)],xdim, ydim,3); % make a colored image for this bg element
        scene=(scene.*(layer==0))+layer; % add the bg element to the scene by blanking the scene where this ellipse/pacman should go, then adding the ellipse/pacman to the scene
        scene_temp=scene+((scene==0).*bg); % color in the remaining bits of screen (background 'field')
        % following bit creates jpegs for levels 1-5 of oneplace as the bg
        % elements are added to the image. i = number of bg elements
        % format 'scene_number_level'
        if i == 1
            imwrite(permute(scene_temp,[2 1 3]),['scene_' int2str(scene_counter) '_' int2str(3) '.jpg'], 'jpg');end;
        if i == 2
            imwrite(permute(scene_temp,[2 1 3]),['scene_' int2str(scene_counter) '_' int2str(4) '.jpg'], 'jpg');end;
        if i == bg_count
            imwrite(permute(scene_temp,[2 1 3]),['scene_' int2str(scene_counter) '_' int2str(5) '.jpg'], 'jpg');end


    end


    image(scene);

    %-------------------------------------------
    % this bit defines coordinates for the s+, s- and big background letter, which get drawn in Presentation
    spacing_flag=1;
    while spacing_flag>0

        letter_centres = [  round(rand*(xdim-300))+150-(0.5*xdim)   round(rand*(ydim-300))+150-(0.5*ydim);          % big background letter can go anywhere more than 150 pixels from the edge
            round(round((rand*15)+0.5).*(xdim./16)-0.5*xdim)
            round(round((rand*11)+0.5).*(ydim./12)-0.5*ydim);
            round(round((rand*15)+0.5).*(xdim./16)-0.5*xdim)        round(round((rand*11)+0.5).*(ydim./12)-0.5*ydim)]; % using 11x15 grid of possible target & distractor positions to match old program

        spacing_flag=sqrt(sum((letter_centres(2,:)-letter_centres(3,:)).^2))<(round(xdim*(427/800))); % min spacing is from old scenes, as determined by Phil
    end

    %-------------------------------------------
    % define characters and fonts
    letter_indices=[round((rand*62)+0.5) round((rand*62)+0.5) round((rand*62)+0.5)];
    font_indices=  [round((rand*10)+0.5) round((rand*10)+0.5) round((rand*10)+0.5)];

    %-------------------------------------------

    scene_info(scene_counter,:)=[scene_counter bg_count letter_indices font_indices...
        letter_centres(1,:) letter_centres(2,:) letter_centres(3,:)...
        round(colors(9,:).*255) round(colors(10,:).*255) round(colors(11,:).*255)];

end

dlmwrite('scene_info.txt',scene_info);
```

Please let me know if I can clarify any of the code and, again, I very much appreciate any help!

Comment: To be honest I don't see the problem. Why don't you just sort the ellipses? btw it would be way easier to discuss if you slim down your sample code to a short self contained example(http://sscce.org/) - just where the ellipses are drawn. Then tell us where your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than define the sizes of the ellipses in the loop, define a list of random parameters before, sort them, then reference the sorted list in the loop. I.e.:

```
a = rand(6,1)*(ell_size_max-ell_size_min)+ell_size_min; % random axis 1
b = rand(6,1)*(ell_size_max-ell_size_min)+ell_size_min; % random axis b

areas = % code for the area of an ellips
[~,order] = sort(areas);
a = a(order);
b = b(order);

for i = 1 : 6
    % Stuff

    ellipse = (x-centre(1)).^2 / a(i)^2 + (y-centre(2)).^2/b(i)^2 < 1; 

    % More stuff
end
```